# OpenPop Pop3 winform MaxMessage c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have problem with messages in mail program. If i have 20 mails it's ok load pretty fast but if i have 700 it's a problem it take a long of time. I can go make coffe and back. How I can set max messages to 50.

```
        try
        {

            client.Connect(comboBox5.Text, 995, true);
            client.Authenticate(textBox6.Text, textBox5.Text, OpenPop.Pop3.AuthenticationMethod.UsernameAndPassword);

      int count = client.GetMessageCount();
            string htmlContained = "";


            for (int i = count; i >= 1; i -= 1)
            {

                OpenPop.Mime.Message message = client.GetMessage(i);

                OpenPop.Mime.MessagePart html = message.FindFirstHtmlVersion();


                if (html != null)
                {

                    htmlContained = html.GetBodyAsText();


                } else
                {
                    html = message.FindFirstPlainTextVersion();
                    if (html != null)
                    {
                        htmlContained = html.GetBodyAsText();
                    }
                }
                string name = message.Headers.Subject;
                if (name == "")
                {
                    name = "Usigned";
                }

                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { name.ToString(), message.Headers.From.DisplayName, message.Headers.From.Address, htmlContained, message.Headers.DateSent });

            }

                client.Disconnect();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = count; i >= 1; i -= 1)
```

->

```
for (int i = 0; i < count && i < 50; i++)
```

Or (less redable according to me):

```
for (int i = count; i >= 1; && (count - i) < 50; i -= 1)
```

You may also want to implement paging:

```
var pageSize = 50;
var startPage = x;

for (int i = x * pageSize; i < count && i < pageSize; i++)
```